# Converting plain php application's user system to symfony2's

Tags: symfony, authentication

I'm converting a website written in plain php to symfony2.I want to put up a functional website and slowly rewrite my way around it, as suggested in the sources I've read, But I can't seem to find a way to use my user system without completely rewriting it the symfony2 way.What I want is to not rewrite that right now but I want my website to be functional.e.g:
all the requests of my website go through an index.php file with get queries to specify the page. e.g: /index.php?page=foo.So in order to use the routing system in symfony2 I've created a "catch-all" controller wich intercepts all requests , overrides the globals using the request object, includes the index.php file, takes the response from that and sends it.Now I want to get rid of the index.php file, but I can't find a way to use the "user authentication (and authorization) system" implemented in it.How can I do that?a possible solution seems to  be implementing it in the front controller since all requests go through it and it's practically equivalent to my index.php file in some ways, but that doesn't seem like good practice.
this the code of the aforementioned catch-all controller:

```
    function indexAction(Request $request){
        $request->overrideGlobals();
        include "/index.php";
        $response = new Response();
        $response->setContent( $html );
        return $response;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Symfony package already included of front controllers web/app_dev.php for 'devlopment mode' and web/app.php for 'production mode'. It is not possible to run your whole plain PHP code to run  in symfony package without minimum modifying according to symfony2 for which you may follow the [Symfony2 versus Flat PHP](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/from_flat_php_to_symfony2.html).

for user authentication and authorization you may follow [Symfony2 Security](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html)